# How to add legend to a 3D scatter graph using Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, legend, highcharts

I am trying to add a legend to a 3d graph using highchart but i am unable to do that..How can i achieve that ?

Below is the jsfiddle code

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tn8w4zmc/2/)

Below is the code i added for legend but its not working...

```
          var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
          chart: {
              renderTo: 'container',
              margin: 100,
              type: 'scatter3d',
              animation: false,
              options3d: {
                  enabled: true,
                  alpha: 10,
                  beta: 30,
                  depth: 150,
                  viewDistance: 5,

              }
          },

          plotOptions: {
              scatter: {
                  width: 10,
                  height: 10,
                  depth: 10
              }
          },
          yAxis: {
            categories: snr,
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            labels: {
              format: '{value:.2f}'
          }
          },
          xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            categories: mac,
            title: {
                text: null
            }
          },
          zAxis: {
            //  categories: count,
              min: 0,
             },


     legend: {
         align: 'right',
         layout: 'vertical',
         margin: 0,
         verticalAlign: 'top',
         y: 25
     },
         legend :{
            enabled : false
          },
          series: [{
              name: 'Reading',
              colorByPoint: true,

      });
```

Please guide me to display the legend in the 3d graph...

[image: I need something like this]

Comment: Just go over all your options and you will find the reason.. `legend.enabled = false`.

Comment: @PawełFus - If i enable also its not coming..

Comment: It's coming: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tn8w4zmc/5/

Comment: @PawełFus - I need something like the image i have uploaded

Comment: Then you should create multiple series, according to the value of a point - right now you have just one series.